# Google Spreadsheet - periodically stamp sheet contents

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

As the title, is there a way to have a "print" of the content of a sheet periodically?
i.a., I'd like to have a trigger that every Monday at 08.15 A.M. copy the contents of a group of a cell of a sheets into another specific group of cell of another sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet.getSheetByName("mySheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet.getSheetByName("mySheet2");
sheet1.getrange("A1:C7").setvalues(sheet1.getrange("B1:D7").getvalues);
```

Where A1:C7 is the destination range and B1:D7 is the source range. I have not tested it but it should be like this.

Comment: yes, I think it works, but I have to do it manually each time. What I mean is the ability to automatically execute this function at a specific date. Do you think is it possible?
@eddyparkinson can you give an example?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just create a method, put the code and create a periodic trigger on some day. Thats all :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Hari.
But, as I can see, you can only select a range, not a specific hour. How can I solve?

Comment: I am talking about trigger in script editor not about range in spreadsheet. In script editor there is an option to create trigger on a given date.

Comment: Sure, what I mean is that in the trigger options you can only select a range.
i.e. I can't set "Every Monday at 08:15 a.m.", but just "Every Monday from 08:00 to 09:00 a.m."

Comment: When you set a trigger it does not mean that it will exactly start at that time with millisecond accuracy. It may trigger after some seconds. So you can not set the trigger at 8:15. Rather you should set at 8-9 which means that it will start the trigger around 8 O' clock.

Comment: Thanks!! Btw this is the right code
{
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname1");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname2");
  sheet2.getRange("B3:B9").setValues(sheet1.getRange("B4:B10").getValues());
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, google-apps-script will do that. It is easy if you know how to program.

This also might do what you need. Some spreadsheet formulas that can insert, update, transmit and add a user interface. www.cellmaster.com.au/Stack.html - It is something I have been working on, a few people are using it.